# how to append text in angular after set interval of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a simple in jquery in which I append the text in div .I am able to that 
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/rgeHe/
But same thing I need to using angular .js but It is not append the data ..why ?how it is possible ?here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/Vzq8yQdb52fJaE7Odv4X?p=preview

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="cntrl">
      <div ng-repeat="i in items">{{i}}</div>
    </div>
      </body>
      <script>
      var app=angular.module('app',[]);
      app.controller('cntrl',function($scope,$interval){
        $scope.items=[];
        var i=0;
        $interval(function(){
          $scope.items.push("Hiii I am div");
          $scope.apply();
        },1000)
      })

      </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `scope.$apply()` ($timeout will already invoke digest cycle and you will end up getting errors for trying to invoke digest when it is already in progress) from the `$timeout` and provide a `track by` on array index otherwise it will fail for duplicate keys since the array contains just the string it will be automatically taken as the key, and using same string will cause duplicate keys. Another way would be to change it to array of objects which holds the string. Ex:- `$scope.items.push({name: "Hiii I am div"});`

```
<div ng-controller="cntrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in items track by $index">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

and

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('cntrl',function($scope,$interval){
    $scope.items=[];
    var i=0;
    $interval(function(){
      $scope.items.push("Hiii I am div");
    },1000)
  })
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vxCn88sG2WCACaUbDvM5?p=preview)**

Comment: Not working …!! it only print one line..please check my fiddle

Comment: @user2535959 where is your fiddle. Just check the demo i have provided

Comment: @user2535959 your plunkr works for me. Where are you trying this.

Comment: but it is  not appending it is creating new divs.if you see fiddle it is not creating div it work in same div and append text in that

Comment: @user2535959 You need to have some node for applying ng-repeat, you cannot do that on a text node. But you could use a span inside the div and ng-repeat it like this. http://plnkr.co/edit/vxCn88sG2WCACaUbDvM5?p=preview . Or another way would be to create a format filter to format and display the value. Or invoke a method on the scope to have the value appended like this http://plnkr.co/edit/B24UAS?p=preview However you have the two fundamental issue as you mentioned in my answer which you need to fix anyways.